# How to extract a rest response that don't have a "name"

Tags: rest-assured

How do you extract an object in a response body that doesn't have a name?

payload example :

```
[
    "0UOIP8AB45B138752172",
    "16GW0K3I6SX162376934",
    "16JMPMJWB1P111816144",
    "1ATU22DNPF2115778748",
    "1MD7WEAY3VX166052653",
    "2G8ITN9TM04162374892",
    "2GJR1LBMCZJ187945453",
    "2RK7A3YGTAA105827565",
    "2SZ04KI5NYO185742410",
    "2ZPHJYIDHOL193996774"
]
```

RestAssured snippet.

```
        RequestSpecification requestSpecification = new RequestSpecBuilder()
                .setBaseUri(domain).build();
        return given()
                .spec(requestSpecification).log().all()
                .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header(X_AUTH_TOKEN, token)
                .get(path).then()
                .assertThat().statusCode(201).log().ifError()
                .extract().path(); // what do I write here?
```

Comment: The payload that you have posted is not a proper json.

Comment: It's a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload that you have posted is not a proper json. However, assuming this is you JSON

```
[ "0UOIP8AB45B138752172",
  "16GW0K3I6SX162376934",
  "16JMPMJWB1P111816144",
  "1ATU22DNPF2115778748",
  "1MD7WEAY3VX166052653",
  "2G8ITN9TM04162374892",
  "2GJR1LBMCZJ187945453",
  "2RK7A3YGTAA105827565",
  "2SZ04KI5NYO185742410",
  "2ZPHJYIDHOL193996774"
]
```

You can't use `path` method since you don't have a path here. However, you can extract this JSON data as a String array data.

```
String[] jsonData = given()
            .spec(requestSpecification).log().all()
            .contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(X_AUTH_TOKEN, token)
            .post(path).then()
            .assertThat().statusCode(201).log().ifError()
            .extract().as(String[].class);
//Add any assertions on the length of the array.
return jsonData[position];                     // Assuming position is the index of the String value to be retrieved.
```

Here, you have to indeed know the position of the value you want to extract out of an JSON array data.